# Finding out total sales based on stocks traded within 90 days from a list of transactions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet which is a list of stock transactions with the following details
Date,StockName,Transaction(Buy/Sell),Quantity,Rate,Total

I need to figure out a way to find 'sell' transactions which occurred within 90 days of buying the stock by first in first out method.

There can be multiple transactions of buy and sell of the same StockName in any order.

I'm a programmer and can do this with the help of vbscript, but I was wondering if excel has a way to calculate this without using vbscript.

If its possible, I would appreciate if someone points me in the right direction and I can figure out the rest.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi David, I'm not asking asking for anyone to do my task for me, I'm not a daily excel user and only wish that someone who's experienced in excel to point me in the right direction (if there is one). i.e. which specific feature of excel I could use to accomplish what I need, except vbscript.

I have tried pivot tables but I think they wont help me.
If no one answers I'll assume its difficult or complex to do it without using vbscript.
If that's the case I'll just write a script on my own to accomplish it and post it here along with a sample.

Comment: Hi Please post what efforts you have taken to accomplish your requirement - else it will be difficult to get some one point out the right direction.... Appreciate that you are a programmer - so getting around this will be easy here when you show your efforts